# dojo 1.8: value indicator when selecting

Tags: dojo

Hi I have set up dijit/select but the problem is that I am not sure tow to capture and indicate the value when selecting. I have seen dijit/form select, dojo.query and  dojo/on. But I am still not able to come up with solution. Can you pls advise? Thanks

```
var select_Card = new Select
(
 {name:'select_PCBA',
  options:
       [
  {label:"<span id='NotinUse'><b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp. . .</b></span>", value:"", selected:true},
 {label:"<span id='NotinUse'><b>&nbsp&nbspA Card</b></span>", value:"a" },
 {label:"<span id='inUse'><b>&nbsp&nbspB Card</b></span>", value:"b"},
 {label:"<span id='NotinUse'><b>&nbsp&nbspC Card</b></span>", value:"c"},
 {label:"<span id='NotinUse'><b>&nbsp&nbspD Card</b></span>", value:"d"},
 {label:"<span id='NotinUse'><b>&nbsp&nbspE Card</b></span>", value:"e"},
       ], style:{width:'150px'}
},"select_Card");

    var card = dom.byId('inUse');   
on(card,'click', function(evt)
{
     alert('Item selected is'+ card.value);
    });
```

Clement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onChange` event of the widget is what you want.

```
on(select_Card, 'change', function(newValue){
    alert(newValue);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/udJuv/

Comment: Hi Craig. Thanks. How do you know about the cards though I did not  put the cards here in this code? I am surprised to see the cards in your jsfidder though I put only A to E in this code here. Nevertheless. Thank you.

Comment: That fiddle was originally built for your other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334959/add-bold-and-font-to-dijit-form-select-programatically/14341385#comment19957526_14341385  I just enhanced it to answer this one.